# javascript jqplot dynamic array inside an array

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm using jqplot.cs and it initializes its data points with an array inside an array like this

var line1 = [['2008-08-12 4:00PM', 4], ['2008-09-12 4:00PM', 6.5], ['2008-10-12 4:00PM', 5.7], ['2008-11-12 4:00PM', 9], ['2008-12-12 4:00PM', 8.2]];

But I'm getting my data points dynamically so how would I create the line1 array dynamically?

I thought I could build a string and then send that into the array like below but that didn't work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < gvWellSamples.Rows.length; i++) {
            sample_date = gvWellSamples.Rows[i].Cells['sample_date'].Value;
            water_elevation = gvWellSamples.Rows[i].Cells['water_elevation'].Value;

            datapoints= datapoints + "['" + sample_date + "'," + water_elevation + "],";
        }
    datapoints = datapoints.substring(0, datapoints.length - 1);


    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [datapoints], {
                title: 'Default Date Axis',
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
                    }
                },
                series: [{ lineWidth: 4, markerOptions: { style: 'square' } }]
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing `datapoints` as a string while it should be an array (like in example you gave with line1)
so it should be constructed something like this:

```
var datapoints = [];
for (var i = 0; i < gvWellSamples.Rows.length; i++) {
        //assuming this gives you correct date
        sample_date = gvWellSamples.Rows[i].Cells['sample_date'].Value;
        //assuming this gives you correct value
        water_elevation = vWellSamples.Rows[i].Cells['water_elevation'].Value;

        datapoints.push([sample_date, water_elevation]);
    }
```

Also if you really need to update the chart data dynamically after you plotted it with `$.jqplot(...` you would have to destroy it with `plot1.destroy()` and redraw it with `$.jqplot(...` again (you could wrap that in one func)